# Race condition while using Stringbuffer as instance variable in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety, race-condition, stringbuffer

My code is like that

```
public class MyServlet extends Action
{
    Stringbuffer s=null;

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    {

        s = "hello";//or some dynamic value 

    }
}
```

Here my question is whether this instance variable 's' would be thread safe or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No! its not ThreadSafe

Comment: What could be the possible reason

Comment: Shouldn't it be "s= new StringBuffer()"?

Comment: @pdem..how will it matter for its thread safety

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instance of Stringbuffer, so it's not thread safe. While StringBuffer is thread safe in itself if you try to perform any further operation on StringBufer.

Comment: But ActionServlet is a singelton class so the member field may b shared between users..The result is that one user can see another user's data..

Comment: I am a newbie for struts please correct me if I go wrong

Comment: Yes that's what i mentioned. You are creating instance of stringbuffer within execute method, so its not thread safe as you say its a property of your action servlet and freely available to all the users of it. One might update it to new value while the other still see's the same old value.

Comment: As Stringbuffer is thread safe by itself so Will it be possible for two threads to access the same instance simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

as per as i think instance variable in **servlets** are *not threadsafe* because only one instance of servlet class is created and shared by all the request threads. **struts** follows **servlet** model.

a class is described as "thread-safe" doesn't mean it is always thread-safe. If individual methods are synchronized, that may not be enough—you may be better off putting in synchronization at a higher level.

because on same StringBuffer Object multiple Threads can change the state of object. suppose one thread is calling one method `append` and appended some String. after this other thread replace some character from same object. at this event, first thread will not be aware of changes done in object.
so we need extra Thread Safety while using Thread-Safe type.

Comment: @androidDev: you can read more on Thread-Safe classes in Kathy sierra's book.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer is ThreadSafe because its implementation is synchronized. But your implementation is not thread safe.

It will be Thread safe if you work on the StringBuffer instance: there are 2  main problems in your implementation:

- you set the value to "null" => it need to be instanciated only one time to get the synchronisation of your instance.
- you set the value in execute => this is not Thread safe because the affectation is not synchronized: use only the method of StringBuffer to set the value.

so the Correct code should be:

```
 public class MyServlet extends Action
 {
 Stringbuffer s=new StringBuffer();

   public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,     HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
   {
      s.setLength(0);// if you want to replace value
      s.append("hello");//or some dynamic value 

   }
}
```

Edit: reformulation

Comment: Ok... I will try this approach

Comment: I tried this approach but my code stopped working as assignment itself is taking stringbuffer as parameter which has some value in it......so if I set its length to 0 it remove the previous value....and also I can't use append method as my code is breaking that way

Comment: Please suggest some other approach

Answer (score 0):

In this case `s` is a *reference* to an object and is not thread safe regardless of which class it points to.  However, this MyServlet object shouldn't be accessed by more than one thread ever, so the fact it is not thread safe is quite reasonable.

BTW Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder ten years ago.

Comment: Struts1 actions are singletons. They're notre request-scoped l'île on Struts2

Comment: @JBNizet Correct, thank you. it should have read "shouldn't be accessed by more than one thread" not "should..."